# About ROS on Ubuntu11.04

Tags: ubuntu-natty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to build Ros on ubuntu11.04.But cant add dependencies.What to do??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10018/about-ros-on-ubuntu11.04/) by [Sohil](https://answers.ros.org/users/572/sohil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-21

Post score: -4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-21**:
Vote to close, duplicate of: http://answers.ros.org/question/618/ros-packages-for-ubuntu-1104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

duplicate of: http://answers.ros.org/question/618/ros-packages-for-ubuntu-1104

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0